# How do I get Safecrackin'?

Tags: west-of-loathing

I've run into a few instances where the Safecrackin' skill could come in handy and I've finally come across a part where I think it's required to progress. However, I haven't been able to find a book on how to learn this skill. How do I get the Safecrackin' skill?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vendors will occasionally sell a skillbook. Some of these books teach class skills, others teach misc skills. I learned safecrackin from a book I bought from Wanderin' Sally. I've seen other books sold by the main store in Dirtwater.

The safecracking book is called *Get Crackin': A Guide to Modern Safes*. (thanks @yuuki)

Also note that buying multiples of the same skillbook does not increase your level in the skill, you have to use XP for that.

Comment: Of course, right after I post this question, I run into Wanderin' Sally for the fourth time and she has a copy *Get Crackin': A Guide to Modern Safes*.